# SAP Hybris 1905 - Update OOTB 'relation'

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm looking at updating an OOTB 'relation', just wanted to add 'ordered=true'.

**OOTB**

\hybris\bin\modules\commerce-services\commerceservices\resources\commerceservices-items.xml

```
<relation code="PoS2WarehouseRel" localized="false"
            generate="true" autocreate="true">
<description>This relation determines available warehouses for the point of service.</description>
<deployment table="PoS2WarehouseRel" typecode="6217" />
       <sourceElement qualifier="pointsOfService" type="PointOfService"
                cardinality="many" />
    <targetElement qualifier="warehouses" type="Warehouse"
                cardinality="many" collectiontype="list" />             
</relation>
```

In my extension core, myextncore-items.xml, I overwrote the OOTB relation,

```
<relation code="PoS2WarehouseRel" localized="false"
                  generate="true" autocreate="false">
<description>This relation determines available warehouses for the point of service.</description>
<sourceElement qualifier="pointsOfService" type="PointOfService"
                           cardinality="many" />
<targetElement qualifier="warehouses" type="Warehouse"
                cardinality="many" collectiontype="list" ordered="true"/>
</relation>
```

But getting error - [ycheckdeployments] No deployment defined for relation PoS2WarehouseRel

Then I tried, Updating to a new code name, added a 'deployment' element,

```
<relation code="PoS2WarehouseRelNew" localized="false"
                  generate="true" autocreate="true">
<description>This relation determines available warehouses for the point of service.</description>
    <deployment table="PoS2WarehouseRelNew" typecode="13000" />
    <sourceElement qualifier="pointsOfService" type="PointOfService"
                           cardinality="many" />
    <targetElement qualifier="warehouses" type="Warehouse"
                cardinality="many" collectiontype="list" ordered="true"/>
</relation>
```

This time getting error - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Attribute warehouses from PoS2WarehouseRelNew relation is already declared in Warehouse

How do I define/update a relation between 'pointsOfService' and 'warehouses' ?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** The given [link](https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8bff7a568669101488a5e40cb7bbd0b9.html) included `relationType` has ordered property but xsd file hasn't got. I haven't tried this yet, may be compiler give an error.

Relations haven't got `ordered` attribute. ordered attribute exist on collections. You can check `xxx-item.xml` file schema `item.xsd`in module folder.

Comment: That is not correct. Have a look here: https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/8bff7a568669101488a5e40cb7bbd0b9.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the example here helps:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/bae7ed9732a4423f867114217ae21b46.html

In that example they redeclared the Collection attribute on one end of the itemtype. But looks hacky...

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem. No deployment was defined and when i did - got the same exception. In my case it was all about changing name in qualifier.

In this case i would change it to "posWarehouses" ;)